# Create, save file with date variable in filename

Tags: batch-file, adb, dos

Trying to use the following to create a .txt file and save it with a custom filename that includes userinput variable and a date string. I can get it to name the file as the UserInput, but not the other elements (date, free text).

```
@echo off
set /p UserInputPath= Filename for Client Log?:
adb logcat > %DATE%_%UserInputPath%_ClientLog.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes:

"%DATE%_%UserInputPath%_ClientLog.txt"

Answer (score 1):

This is a robust method of getting the date

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%

set /p UserInputPath= Filename for Client Log?:
adb logcat > "%stamp%_%UserInputPath%_ClientLog.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>"%DATE:/=-%_%UserInputPath%_ClientLog.txt" adb logcat
```

Comment: Thanks. I put this in, but now I get "access is denied" when I run the batch

Comment: What rings alarm-bells for me here is the variablename used for user input. `UserInputPath` could invite a full-pathname, including maybe the drive. Perhaps `"%UserInputPath%%DATE:/=-%_ClientLog.txt"` would be preferable.

Comment: Yes, and user input may contain forbidden characters like `:/\<>|*?"`.